# set up DERBY_HOME environment variable on Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, configuration, javadb

I'm trying to configure my system to allow for Java DB/derby.

I changed the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable through *Advanced system settings* of the *Control Panel* by following the tutorial on [this website](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/).

I opened the command prompt to run `setEmbeddedCP.bat` with following command line:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin>setEmbeddedCP.bat
```

And this was the output:

> DERBY_HOME or DERBY_INSTALL not set. Set one of these variables
>   to the location of your Derby installation.

I'm searching online for answers. I'm not sure if I should open the bat file directly and change the variables in that file or go through *Advanced system settings* again. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
@rem set DERBY_INSTALL=%JAVA_HOME%\db

@if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" set DERBY_HOME=%DERBY_INSTALL%
@if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" goto noderbyhome

@FOR %%X in ("%DERBY_HOME%") DO SET DERBY_HOME=%%~sX

set CLASSPATH=%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbytools.jar;%DERBY_HOME%/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar;%CLASSPATH%
@goto end

:noderbyhome
@echo DERBY_HOME or DERBY_INSTALL not set. Set one of these variables
@echo to the location of your Derby installation.
@goto end

:end
```

Comment: what is the content of the `setEmbeddedCP.bat` ?

Comment: I added the file above @npocmaka

Comment: Looks like you'll have to download [derby](http://apache.cbox.biz//db/derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.zip) unzip it somewhere and the same way you created java_home variable you'll need to create another one that points to the unziped folder called `derby_home` . Be sure that `%derby_home%\lib\derby.jar` is a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

The third command line of `setEmbeddedCP.bat` checks if environment variable `DERBY_HOME` is defined which is not the case in your environment resulting in getting the error message output.

The second command line assigns value of environment variable `DERBY_INSTALL` to variable `DERBY_HOME` if `DERBY_HOME` is not defined.

The first line **would** define the variable `DERBY_INSTALL` with path to subdirectory `db` in directory of *Java*, but this line is commented out because of command **rem**.

So with *Derby* installed in subdirectory `db` of *Java* directory all you need to do use removing the command **rem** and the space after this command.

By the way: This batch file is coded ugly. Better would be:

```
@echo off

rem Define installation directory of Derby which is by default the
rem subdirectory "db" in directory of Java. Modify this line if the
rem files derby.jar, derbytools.jar and derbyoptionaltools.jar are
rem not installed into subdirectory "db\lib" of the Java directory.
rem Altenatively the environment variable DERBY_HOME can be defined
rem with path to main directory of Derby installation to use.

set "DERBY_INSTALL=%JAVA_HOME%\db"

if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" set "DERBY_HOME=%DERBY_INSTALL%"
if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" (
    echo Error detected by %~f0:
    echo.
    echo DERBY_HOME or DERBY_INSTALL not set. Set one of these
    echo variables to the location of your Derby installation.
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

rem Get directory path of DERBY in short 8.3 format.
for %%X in ("%DERBY_HOME%") do set "DERBY_HOME=%%~sX"

rem Define the class path with additional Derby Java archives.
set "CLASSPATH=%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbytools.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar;%CLASSPATH%"
```

It looks like batch file `setEmbeddedCP.bat` is in subdirectory `bin` of the Derby installation directory `db` in directory of *Java*.

Taking this fact into account, the batch file `setEmbeddedCP.bat` could determine installation respectively home directory of Derby by itself with two simple lines at top of the batch file instead of line with command **set**.

```
@echo off

rem Define installation directory of Derby which is by default the
rem subdirectory "db" in directory of Java. This batch file is by
rem default in the subdirectory "bin" of the Derby directory "db".
rem Determine the Derby installation directory from directory of
rem this batch file.

set "DERBY_INSTALL=%~dp0"
set "DERBY_INSTALL=%DERBY_INSTALL:\bin\=%"

rem Altenatively the environment variable DERBY_HOME can be defined
rem with path to main directory of Derby installation to use.

if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" set "DERBY_HOME=%DERBY_INSTALL%"
if "%DERBY_HOME%"=="" (
    echo Error detected by %~f0:
    echo.
    echo DERBY_HOME or DERBY_INSTALL not set. Set one of these
    echo variables to the location of your Derby installation.
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

rem Get directory path of DERBY in short 8.3 format.
for %%X in ("%DERBY_HOME%") do set "DERBY_HOME=%%~sX"

rem Define the class path with additional Derby Java archives.
set "CLASSPATH=%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbytools.jar;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar;%CLASSPATH%"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `got /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`